# state in not setting on value change in picker in react native

Tags: react-native

hi i am using picker component from native base ..and i am getting value in it from API ..now i want to change my select value but when i select one value from all of these my state is not changing ... here is my code of picker and function which i am applying right now .. help me please i am already running out of time :(

```
<Item picker >
        <Left>
       <Text style={{paddingLeft:10,fontSize:15,fontWeight:'bold',color:this.state.backgroundColor}}>Current State</Text>
       </Left>
       <Body>
          <Picker 
            mode="dropdown"
            iosIcon={<Icon name="ios-arrow-down-outline" />}
            style={{ width: '100%' }}

            placeholder="Change state"

            placeholderStyle={{ color: "#bfc6ea" }}
            placeholderIconColor="#007aff"
           selectedValue={this.state.state_id}
            // onValueChange={this.onValueChange2.bind(this)}
           onValueChange={(value)=>this.valueChangeOFCountry(value)}
          >
            {myState}
          </Picker>
          </Body>

        </Item>


valueChangeOFCountry(value){

this.setState({updateCountry:value})


alert(this.state.updateCountry)
```

}

Comment: How does the function *this.onValueChange* look like? And what is *myState*?

Comment: i have post my function body in my question you can check there..and mystate is array whch i used to show my data ..that data i am taken from API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method "valueChangeOFCountry" definition should be as es6.
And wait for setState to update your state. Hopefully this will help

```
valueChangeOFCountry = (value) => {
this.setState({updateCountry: value}, 
  ()=> alert(this.state.updateCountry)
}
```

Comment: now i update my question i write wrong function name

Comment: yup its working but can u tell me why my function not working ??infact i did the samethings in my function but style is different

Comment: Because your Function call is as es6 " onValueChange={(value)=>this.valueChangeOFCountry(value)}", but function definition was according to es5 valueChangeOFCountry(value){ ... }

Comment: And this .setState({...}) take some  time to update the state and reflects the changes. you was not waiting to set its state and called alert() ..